# How can pgsql sequence be undefined when I just called nextval?

Tags: postgresql, session, sequence

I've got an app built on top of PostgresQL, which makes use of a custom sequence.  I think I understand sequences pretty well by now: they are non-transactional, currval is defined only within the current session, etc.  But I don't understand this:

```
2015-10-13 10:37:16 SQLSelect: SELECT nextval('commit_id_seq')
2015-10-13 10:37:16 commit_id_seq: 57
2015-10-13 10:37:16 SQLExecute: UPDATE bid SET is_archived=false,company_id=1436,contact_id=15529,...(etc)...,sharing_policy='' WHERE id = 56229
2015-10-13 10:37:16 ERROR: ERROR:  currval of sequence "commit_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO history (table_name, record_id, sec_user_id, created, action, notes, status, before, after, commit_id)
        SELECT TG_TABLE_NAME, rec.id, (SELECT id FROM sec_user WHERE name = CURRENT_USER), now(), SUBSTR(TG_OP,1,1), note, stat, oldH, newH, currval('commit_id_seq')"
PL/pgSQL function log_to_history() line 28 at SQL statement
 [3]
```

We log every call to the database, and in the case of the SELECT nextval, I also log the result.  The above are the exact calls, except that I trimmed the UPDATE statement (because the original is really long).

So, you can see that we *just called* nextval on the sequence, got a reasonable number back, and then we do an UPDATE that invokes a trigger function that attempts to use currval on that sequence... and it fails, claiming currval is not defined.

Note that this doesn't usually happen, but once it does start happening, it does so consistently (perhaps until the user disconnects from the DB).

How can this be?  And what can I do about it?

Comment: Interesting. Do you use any middleware for connection pooling or load balancing like `pgpool-II` or `pgBouncer`? Maybe your client library performs connection pooling? Does the problem go away when you'd explicitly do `nextval` and `update` in single transaction?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you'd log backend PID - add `%p` to `log_line_prefix` configuration option or use `pg_backend_pid()` in explicit logging.

Comment: We do not use an explicit transaction.  Connection pooling in the client library is a possibility.  I'll look into whether we can log the backend PID.

Comment: Why are you even using nextval() and currval()? If you already fetched the nextval() result, you can as well build this value into your query string.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` statement obviously calls a trigger. The most plausible cause of this error is that the trigger function is in a different schema from where the sequence is defined and the schema of the sequence is not in the `search_path`. That gives you two options to resolve this:

1. Make the schema of the sequence visible to the trigger function using `SET search_path TO ...`. Note that this will make *all objects* in the schema of the sequence visible, which may be something of a security risk, depending on your database design.
2. Schema-qualify the sequence name in the trigger function: `currval('my_schema.commit_id_seq')`.

Another plausible cause is connection pooling at your application end. [Log the "session ID"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html) (really just the starting time and `pid` of the current session) by adding `%c` to your `log_line_prefix()` parameter in `postgresql.conf`. In PostgreSQL every command runs in its own transaction unless a transaction is explicitly established. Connection pooling software also works at the transaction level (i.e. you start a transaction and then your connection will stay open until you close it, outside of a transaction there are no guarantees about session persistence). If that is the case you can wrap your entire set of commands in a `BEGIN ... COMMIT` block (you should probably use a specific call from your pooling software), or better yet, change your code to not depend on a previous `nextval()` call.

Comment: This was an interesting idea, and I spent some time looking into it.  But a \dn shows exactly 1 schema ("public").  We have never used the multiple-schemas feature.  Also, if this were the problem, I would expect it to fail every time, instead of just the occasional failure we're actually seeing.

Comment: Added another possible cause.